# Send Bitmap image from Android and receive it in php server

Tags: php, android, image, bitmap, server

*I did refer to the older articles, not just on SO but all other websites to solve this, they use old Android APIs that are deprecated and so I have to ask it again here.*

I have been successful yet in sending and receiving text data from Android to php server and saving it in MySql database. But I have no idea how should I send and receive my Bitmap image from phone to server.

May be I can convert the bitmap image into string and send it just like any other Strings, but then how can I decode the bitmap String on my php server?

Here is my code to send the text data and I want to send my captured (Bitmap) image as well with the data:

```
public class PostComplaint extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences preferences;
String link; //Getting this from the sharedPreferences which I have removed here

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
ImageButton addImage;
Bitmap photo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_complaint);

    addImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        addImage.setImageDrawable(null);
        addImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        addImage.setImageBitmap(photo);

        //Below I have converted Bitmap into String but I have no idea how to use it
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, baos);
        byte[] photoByte = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(photoByte,Base64.DEFAULT);     
    }
}

public void submit(View view) {
    //Getting text data from EditTexts.
    final String location,problem_type,comment;
    EditText et;
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);
    location = et.getText().toString();
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment);
    comment = et.getText().toString();
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    problem_type = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    HashMap postData = new HashMap();
    postData.put("location",location);
    postData.put("problem_type",problem_type);
    postData.put("comment",comment);

    //I have provided a link to the below library that I have used. 
    PostResponseAsyncTask submitTast = new PostResponseAsyncTask(PostComplaint.this,postData, new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(PostComplaint.this, "" + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    submitTast.execute("http://" + link + "/addComplaint.php");
}
}
```

I do use a library and here is a link to it. ([generic_asynctask_v2](https://github.com/kosalgeek/generic_asynctask_v2))

Comment: if you can send/receive text, then you can send/receive your image. if nothing else, you can encode the bitmap data as a base64 string and send that over like you would any other text.

Comment: @MarcB  If I send that to server, How can I handle that on php?

Comment: @MarcB your answer about base64 helped me, if you can write it as an Answer instead of a comment, i'll mark it accepted. TYSM. (Do not prefer wiring answers for my own questions.)